# Neo4j parallel CREATE queries stuck

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I've a Java application that creates Neo4j relationships between existing nodes. the app has about 16 threads (on 16 CPU cores) and each uses some Cypher like:

```hs
// smRelRows comes from java, as run() parameter
UNWIND $smRelRows AS relRow\s
MATCH ( gene:Gene { appId: relRow.geneId } ),
        ( concept:Concept { appId: relRow.conceptId } )
CREATE (gene) - [:hasMotifLink{ graphDistance: relRow.graphDistance }] -> (concept)
```

The app queues a few thousand tasks doing the above, but its parallelism is limited to only 16 threads. Each query receives 2500 values in `smRelRows` and is run in its own transaction.

The problem is everything is completely stuck, in the Neo4j server, `SHOW TRANSACTIONS` shows the first 16 queries running since the app started.

I suspect some deadlock, due to the lock of relation-shared nodes, but then I don't know I to fix the problem. In the past, I've written similar multi-thread `CREATE`-based updates without problems.

I've added `appId`'s indexes, but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes **are not** locked anymore when you're creating relationships.

For eg this block of code works without issues and produces generally around 65 concurrent transactions.

```java
   private final String query = """
            MATCH (a:Node {id: 1})
            MATCH (b:Node {id: 2})
            CREATE (a)-[r:REL {type: 'demo'}]->(b)
            """;
   @Test
    void parallel_rels() {
        try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "password"))) {
            IntStream.range(1, 10000)
                    .parallel()
                    .forEach(i -> {
                        try (Session session = driver.session(SessionConfig.forDatabase("locking2"))) {
                            session.executeWriteWithoutResult((tx) -> {
                                tx.run(query).consume();
                            });
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

However, this the list of active locks taken when you're creating a relationship :

```
╒═══════════╤════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│mode       │resourceType                    │resourceId         │
╞═══════════╪════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│"EXCLUSIVE"│"RELATIONSHIP"                  │0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"INDEX_ENTRY"                   │649269460893700912 │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"INDEX_ENTRY"                   │-890913567585829783│
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"LABEL"                         │0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"RELATIONSHIP_TYPE"             │0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"RELATIONSHIP_TYPE"             │2147483647         │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"EXCLUSIVE"│"RELATIONSHIP_DELETE"           │0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"NODE_RELATIONSHIP_GROUP_DELETE"│0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"NODE_RELATIONSHIP_GROUP_DELETE"│1                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"DEGREES"                       │0                  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"SHARED"   │"DEGREES"                       │1                  │
└───────────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

The following locks however can happen :

- RelationshipGroup :  if multiple threads would compete to update the head of the relationship group
- Degrees : If you have other transactions that are updating labels on the same nodes, locks will be taken to ensure consistent count stores
- Writes : If you're trying to update properties of the same nodes in other transactions, for sparse nodes ( nodes having less than 50 relationships ) a lock will be taken, for dense nodes not

The best way to investigate what is happening is while all your transactions are running, check the status of the transactions with `SHOW TRANSACTIONS YIELD *` where you can investigate if transactions are blocked by other transactions and which ones

[image]

Then, couple of questions :

- Are you really using `CREATE` for creating the relationship or you're using `MERGE` ?
- What are the constraints in your database -> output of `SHOW CONSTRAINTS`

Comment: what is the `query` variable initialized to in the test?

Comment: @fbiville amended the post with the query

Answer (score 1):

Each relation creation locks onto the start and end node, so you indeed run into [deadlocks](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/database-internals/locks-deadlocks/#deadlocks) when any of the relation start or end node overlaps with another relation being created.

I can see three options of increasing complexity:

1. fall back to sequential imports (`UNWIND` and `CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS` may help)
2. retry failed transactions on deadlock errors up to *n* times
3. separate your relationship by non-overlapping batches (each batch must not have any common start and end nodes in common with other batches)

Comment: @fbville, Many thanks. 1) I can do it from Java (without IN TRANSACTIONS), but single-thread seems slow. 2) Tried that in the past (with a similar case), but now it stops at the first  16 transactions, without any deadlock exception back to Java 3) indeed, I have many hub gene nodes and it's practically impossible to partition the batches.

Answer (score 0):

It's embarrassing, but I'll report the silly mistake I made, which is quite unrelated to parallel relationship creation, yet my experience could be useful.

It turns out that in the pattern `MATCH <nodes> CREATE <relations>`, matching the nodes to be linked by means of indexes makes a huge difference.

In the specific case, I had an index for `Concept.ondexId`, but not for `Gene.ondexId`, for I have been silly enough to believe that Neo4j can understand `Gene` is a subclass of `Concept` in my schema (ie, all nodes with label `Gene` always have the `Concept` label too).

Once I've added the second index too, the speed went to the sky, like a few seconds for 15k relationships on a client with 8 cores (so, yes, I kept parallelism, with batches of 2500 rows).

As [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662355/christophe-willemsen) says, it seems the nodes aren't locked anymore in this kind of statement. In fact, I used to wrap the statements above in a [multiple-attempt manager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662355/christophe-willemsen), which intercepts concurrency exceptions and retries (after a random-time pause), and I don't see any such exception anymore.

Comment: Great you found the root cause